# After Effects: Create an isometric/orthographic Camera

Tags: after-effects, camera, 3d, after-effects-expressions

I know that its not possible to create an non-perspective camera in after effects. But I read about a way to fake the effect of an isometric camera in after effects. I just didn't find something useful in the web so far so I wanted to post the Question about how to create an isometric camera in after effects here so you guys can share your ideas on how to realize this problem.

I just cant get over the fact that its not possible in a mighty program like After Effects.

Thanks for your sharing your opinions and ideas in advance!

Comment: Might be a better idea to use a 3d tool like blender, maybe related: http://www.blendernation.com/2015/02/09/behind-the-scenes-isometric-illusion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a camera with a long focal length.  The longer the focal length, the closer to isometric.  Just back the camera far enough away to frame the shot.

Comment: works pretty well with a focal length of 50000 for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might help, it's a script that creates an [isometric camera view in After Effects](https://madebyloop.co.uk/products/angle-create-isometric-camera-after-effects/)

There's also a short [blog post](https://madebyloop.co.uk/blog/creating-isometric-camera-in-after-effects/) on how it's done which outlines the process:

Step 1. Add a new camera

Step 2. Change the camera settings:

```
Camera Position: 0,0,-5000
Zoom: 5000px
```

Step 3. Add a new null object, make it 3D and parent the camera to it

Step 4. Change the null object rotation to:

```
X Rotation: 35.264
Y Rotation: 35.264
Z Rotation: 35.264
```

Should get you close.

Comment: Can you summarize the contents of the blog post? Answers should really be able to stand on their own in case linked content becomes unavailable.